# Embed not showing correctly

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm having some issues showing lists in my embed correctly. I'm trying to get my roles to under one list title here is the issue I'm having with how my lists are displaying themselves in the embed.

[image]

It seems each role is being duplicated under the list title.

I've tried `inline=True` this doesn't seem to fix the issue.

```
     #--- Below is the list command ---

@commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True, name='list', aliases=['roles', 'role'])
async def _list(self, ctx):
    """List of all available roles """
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    author = ctx.message.author
    botroom = self.bot.get_channel(555844758778544160) 
    intros = self.bot.get_channel(485381365366390796)
     #--- Role list Categories ---"
    Colours = ['Blue', 'Green', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Purple']
    Colours.sort(key=str.lower)

    Games = ['LoL', 'WoW', 'Overwatch']
    Games.sort(key=str.lower)

    Platforms = ['PC', 'Xbox', 'PS4', 'Nintendo Switch']
    Platforms.sort(key=str.lower)

    if ctx.message.channel == intros:
        pass
    else:
        if ctx.message.channel == botroom:
            title = '**Hey {}, here is a list of roles you can add:**'.format(author.display_name)
            embed = discord.Embed(title=title.format(), colour=0x0080c0)
            embed.add_field(name="**Have a role suggestion?**", value="If you can't find the role you want but would like to see it added to the roles list please tell us in <#555371532390760473>.", inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(text="Tip: to add a role from the list type the command !add/remove followed by the role.")

            #Lets start embed roles list below#
            for role in Games:
                embed.add_field(name="**Game Roles**", value="\n{} **({})**".format(role, len([member for member in guild.members if ([r for r in member.roles if r.name == role])])))

            for role in Platforms:
                embed.add_field(name="**Plaforms Roles**", value="\n{} **({})**".format(role, len([member for member in guild.members if ([r for r in member.roles if r.name == role])])))
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.send('You can only use this command in {}.'.format(botroom.mention))
```

Role in lists are not displaying as they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently adding the categories once for each item in the category.  Instead, you want to add each category once, listing all the roles underneath it.  You can also get the role object and access `len(role.members)` directly:

```
def role_name_to_summary(ctx, name):
    role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name=name)
    if not role:
        return None
    return f"{role.name} **({len(role.members)})**"

embed.add_field(name="**Game Roles**", value="\n".join(filter(None, [role_name_to_summary(ctx, name) for name in Games]))
```

Comment: I a bit confused how to use this in my code is def an event? or should that be `async def` could you give me a example in how you'd use this.

Comment: That's just a helper function to make the strings.  You would have that somewhere in your code, and have the line below it replace the `for role in Games:` loop in your command.